# Sauce labs testing with appium desired capabilities opening a safari browser

Tags: java, automated-tests, appium, appium-ios, saucelabs

I am just coding the my desired  capabilities in eclipse using sauce labs. I want to open a web page in safari.

(I should add I am an utter newbie to cloud automated testing.)

When I get to the section of connecting the desired capabilities to sauce labs I am horribly stuck.

I got an error message in eclipse that said 'URL cannot be resolved to a  type'

additionally I am not utterly confident in the IOS driver syntax as it gave an error message

```
References to generic type IOSDriver<T> should be parameterized
```

Here are my questions:

1. how to do fix

> 'URL cannot be resolved to a  type'

2. What is the correct syntax for

> IOSDriver driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://USERNAME:ACCESS_KEY@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub"), cap);
>            driver.get("https://www.bbc.co.uk/");

So I don't get

> References to generic type IOSDriver should be parameterized

so I can **successfully** run these desired capabilities with the correct information.

I would appreciate you assistance and considerable knowledge.

Here is my code

```
package iOSCloudTesting;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSElement;

public class IosCloudSauce {

    public static final String USERNAME = "confidential";
    public static final String ACCESS_KEY = "confidential";
    public static final String URL = "https://" + USERNAME + ":" + ACCESS_KEY + "@ondemand.saucelabs.com:443/wd/hub";

     public static void main(String[] args){

         DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();

         cap.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
         cap.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone8 Simulator");
         cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "11.3");
         cap.setCapability("browserName", "Safari");
         cap.setCapability("deviceOrientation", "portrait");


        IOSDriver driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://USERNAME:ACCESS_KEY@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub"), cap);
         driver.get("https://www.bbc.co.uk/");
```

Comment: (1) You need to import the java.net.URL class (2) Is a warning about missing type parameter. Read up about generics and it should be obvious how to fix it. Your code will still run with the warning anyways.

Comment: qqilihq   so 'URL cannot be resolved to a type'  has a missing type perameter.  Ok,  thanks man, I will look this up.

Comment: qqilihq  Sorry I misread your comment. I meant to say 'URL cannot be resolved to a type' requires importing the URL class.  OK I'm on it I will figure out how to do that.

Comment: qqilihq   thank you so much I was able to remove the URL error message.  My code looks correct.   Thanks so much you are a legend.

Answer (score 0):

Making my comment above a full answer:

> 'URL cannot be resolved to a type'

Add the following import to the top of your file:

```
import java.net.URL;
```

Your IDE should also be able to do that for your automatically. In Eclipse e.g. mark the URL occurrence in your code and use the “Quick Fix” functionality.

> References to generic type IOSDriver should be parameterized

This is a **warning** about a missing type parameter (your code will compile and run, despite the warning). To really fix it, add the type parameter to your constructor invocation. In your case you can probably simply write:

```
IOSDriver<?> driver = new IOSDriver<>(…); // or alternatively:
IOSDriver<IOSElement> = new IOSDriver<>(…);
```

Comment: thank you so much you have been super cool answering this.  I will try that a try.

Comment: Hi,  I just added  IOSDriver<?> driver = new IOSDriver<>(new URL("http://USERNAME:ACCESS_KEY@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub"),cap);  and tried to run my desired capabilities and  got "  Unable to parse remote response: Misconfigured -- Sauce Labs Authentication Error.
You used username 'USERNAME' and access key 'ACCESS_KEY' to authenticate, which are not valid Sauce Labs credentials."  How do I fix this?

Answer (score -1):

Use following line to get proper URL

```
WebDriver driver= new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://USERNAME:ACCESS_KEY@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub"),cap);
```

Comment: Thank  you so much Shital I added this to my cold.  Fingers crossed it works

Comment: just did it.  hope that helps

Comment: In place of 'USERNAME' you have to mention your sauce lab username and in place of 'ACCESS_KEY' you should mention sauce lab access key of your account